# Mobile Responsive Design with CSS

Tags: css, mobile

I have some questions regarding mobile responsive.

- elements tab: Is it only for mobile device code?
- what is sources tab? is it web site code?

I would like to add DIV only for mobile device and that should not be effected to website view. so how do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add div tag only for mobile device,
Use media querie,
For desktop = display:none;
Mobile = display:block;

Comment: Thanks sir. by pressing f12 elements tab appear so this elements tab code only for mobile or desktop also.                                    by inspecting how  to find media css or desktop css ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want add a div only in mobile you can use @media queries and displays.

```css
.mobile{ 
   display: none;
}

.desktop{
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="mobile">Only Mobile</p>
  <p class="desktop">Only Desktop</p>
  <p>Forever</p>
</div>
```

Comment: having issue and css code as below Code A: .topssec { background: #fff; }                                                 
               Code B: @media (max-width: 550px} .topssec { display: block; background: blue; }          
      code A working but code B not working and code B for mobile css. kindly assist how solve to work B not code A.

Comment: After 550px you need write ")"